# How can I install Chrome OS to a CD so I can install it on an x86 machine

Tags: grub, solaris, google-chrome-os, x86, solaris-10

The x86 machine is Sun hardware and it is currently running Solaris and it has a GRUB menu. I would like to preserve my existing Solaris OS if convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome OS is not your typical operating system. It is meant to be distributed ready-installed on new netbooks, and installing it on your system will most probably not work out well.

To try it out, you can try to Apply for the Chrome OS pilot program here:

http://www.google.com/chromeos/pilot-program.html

or, if you're insterested in the development aspect, check out Chromium OS, which is the open-source version that you can play around with, here:

http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os

Still, even with Chromium, you will need to build the source code yourself to run it; so I sincerely don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hexxeh Chromium build site](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/) has a lot of good instructions for installing along side with other operating systems.

[This link](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/wiki/doku.php?id=multiboot) is for Ubuntu, but should be right depending on the version of GRUB you're running.